# shell_exec respond to command

Tags: php, shell

I'm trying to execute command on my server via php script. I have cPanel, but I'm access php file via my domain. Script is:

```
$output = exec('php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

It's working, but output is: `Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]:`

I don't know how to respond to this command. I tried code below but it's not working:

```
exec("php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations")
    $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
    exec("yes");
    $line = fgets($handle);
    if(trim($line) != 'yes'){
        echo "ABORTING!\n";
        exit;
    }
    echo "\n";
    echo "Thank you, continuing...\n";
```

Comment: What is that meant to do: `exec("yes");`? Doesn't make any sense... You need to write (echo) the string into a pipe writing to that commands input. So you need more pipes. You need to launch the command you execute in a different manner to be able to attach pipes to it.

Comment: Not working, it says: Error: Migration failed. Directory specified in migrationPath doesn't exist: @ve
ndor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations;

Comment: "yes" is not command: `'yes' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: It's working now, thank you very much. I made mistake while executing it

Comment: @FosAvance: Which is working? and what was the mistake - that might be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Problem was I was trying to execute that in cmd locally on my laptop first before using this command on live server. It didn't work on cmd but worked using in php script: `exec("yes | php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations")`

Comment: Ah, I figured Windows might've been the issue there (the error about "...batch file..." is not seen on linux) — anyway, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
exec("yes | php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations")
```

In that way you pipe the output of yes to your php script.

Comment: It's not working. I wanted to use "yes" only to confirm that command: Apply the above migrations? (yes|no) [no]. But I don't know how to do it, I was googleing but couldn't find

Comment: have you tried with `exec("echo yes | php yii migrate/up --migrationPath=@vendor/dektrium/yii2-user/migrations")` ?

Comment: It's working now, thank you very much. I made mistake while executing it